# How to convert text to image in PHP with line break?

Tags: php

Currently I am using the PHP code below to convert string text to image with transparent background. Now I need to convert the string text to image with line break, transparent background and also with custom font. Code I am using:

```
$width = 200;
$height = 40;
$text = "Test text -- line break here -- with line break";
$fontsize = 3;
$img = imagecreate($width, $height);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $black);
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($img, $fontsize, 0, 0, $text, $color);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: Okay, we have some background info. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Fluffeh, OP wants a line break between the text which is going to be rendered as an image.

Comment: Try using `\r\n` or `\n` as a linebreak in your text string. Might do the trick.

Comment: there isn't a way to break line ?

Comment: The code `\r\n` or `\n` is a break line. Basically use `$text = "Test text \r\n with line break";` as your input.

Comment: Not sure control characters will be rendered correctly. They may well be, but anyway using `imagestring()` multiple times with different position should give you "line break" too as an alternative...

Comment: Sorry it is not working but how would you embed the custom font here ?

Answer (score 2):

Doing it like this will help you

```
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
$str1= 'Test text '; 
$str2= 'with line break'; 
$image= imagecreate(200,40); 
$background = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255); 
$color= imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0); 
imagefill($image,0,0,$background); 
imagestring($image,10,5,5,$str1,$color); 
imagestring($image,10,5,20,$str2,$color); 
imagepng($image);
```

output look like this

[image]

Comment: Please could you tell me how can I embed the custom font in the script I've posted ?